# Why ComputeSignature in .Net Framework and .Net Core do different result

Tags: .net, .net-core, pkcs#7

I have problem.

```
        var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(message);
        var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
        var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(certificate);

        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
        data = signedCms.Encode();
```

This code in .Net Framework 4.7 and in .Net Core 2.1 do different result...

My message length is 73 bytes

result in .Net Framework - 1520 bytes

result in .Net Core - 1523 bytes

Why?

Answer (score 4):

On .NET Framework, if your .exe is targeting 4.7 or older then `new CmsSigner(cert)` indicates that the signer should use SHA-1 as their digest, at 4.7.1 and higher the default algorithms changed to SHA-2-256.

On .NET Core 2.1 the default is already SHA-2-256.

You can change either of them to whatever digest algorithm you like by setting the `DigestAlgorithm` property of `CmsSigner`.  e.g. `cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");` now makes both of them use SHA-2-256.

Additionally, .NET Framework is encoding the RSA signature algorithm identifier as `{ id-rsaEncryption, NULL }` and .NET Core is encoding it as `{ id-rsaEncryption }` (omitting the optional second value).  This part doesn't change the semantic interpretation of the content, but means that when using the same digest algorithm on both, they still won't come out to the same length.

---

The DER encoding of the SHA-2-256 algorithm identifier is two bytes longer than the DER encoding of the SHA-1 identifier (assuming that the parameters value for SHA-2-256 is omitted, and for SHA-1 it is NULL).  This gets written down twice (+4 to core), then the difference in how the RSA signature algorithm identifier is represented makes the .NET Core version 2 bytes smaller (net: +2 to core)

The reason that you see a *three* byte difference, instead of two, is that some portion of your document structure ends up passing one of the thresholds where the length prefix (which is variable length) needs to gain an extra byte to hold the value.  Those points are the standard "byte boundaries" (255 -> 256, 65535 -> 65536, etc) in addition to 127 -> 128. Your SignerInfo block is likely 254 or 255 bytes on your .NET Framework document, and crosses over to 256 or 257 due to the longer identifier value for SHA-2-256.

Comment: Thanks, but I want .NET Core 2.1 worked like .NET Framework. My application must compute signature to 1520 bytes. How config .net Core (sha1 - Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26") compute 1515 bytes)?

Comment: I set SHA-1 cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26"); end result length is 1515 bytes, not 1520.

Comment: There’s no option to make them produce the exact same bytes. .NET Core leaves off the DER NULL in the identifier for RSA, and no option will put it back. But both products will say each other’s output is valid.

Comment: Bad(( External application who check my signature is got only then I compute in .Net Framework (1520 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using BouncyCastle.NetCore in method "ComputeSignature" (work in Debian 9 with .Net Core 2.0).
Result length is 2537 bytes, but external application working good with this signature.

```
    public static byte[] ComputeSignature(byte[] message, string PrivateKeyPath, string password, string CertPath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load end certificate and signing key
            var signerCert = ReadCertFromFile(PrivateKeyPath, password, out AsymmetricKeyParameter key);

            // Read CA cert
            var caCert = ReadCertFromFile(CertPath);
            var certChain = new X509Certificate[] { caCert };

            var result = SignWithSystem(
              message,
              key,
              signerCert,
              certChain);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed : " + ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected static byte[] SignWithSystem(byte[] data, AsymmetricKeyParameter key, X509Certificate cert, X509Certificate[] chain)
    {
        var generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
        // Add signing key
        generator.AddSigner(
          key,
          cert,
          "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1"); // SHA256 digest ID
        var storeCerts = new List<X509Certificate>
        {
            cert // NOTE: Adding end certificate too
        };
        storeCerts.AddRange(chain); // I'm assuming the chain collection doesn't contain the end certificate already
                                    // Construct a store from the collection of certificates and add to generator
        var storeParams = new X509CollectionStoreParameters(storeCerts);
        var certStore = X509StoreFactory.Create("CERTIFICATE/COLLECTION", storeParams);
        generator.AddCertificates(certStore);

        // Generate the signature
        var signedData = generator.Generate(
          new CmsProcessableByteArray(data),
          false); // encapsulate = false for detached signature
        return signedData.GetEncoded();
    }

    public static X509Certificate ReadCertFromFile(string strCertificatePath)
    {
        // Create file stream object to read certificate
        using (var keyStream = new FileStream(strCertificatePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var parser = new X509CertificateParser();
            return parser.ReadCertificate(keyStream);
        }
    }

    // This reads a certificate from a file.
    // Thanks to: http://blog.softwarecodehelp.com/2009/06/23/CodeForRetrievePublicKeyFromCertificateAndEncryptUsingCertificatePublicKeyForBothJavaC.aspx
    public static X509Certificate ReadCertFromFile(string strCertificatePath, string strCertificatePassword, out AsymmetricKeyParameter key)
    {
        key = null;
        // Create file stream object to read certificate
        using (var keyStream = new FileStream(strCertificatePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Read certificate using BouncyCastle component
            var inputKeyStore = new Pkcs12Store();
            inputKeyStore.Load(keyStream, strCertificatePassword.ToCharArray());

            var keyAlias = inputKeyStore.Aliases.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault(n => inputKeyStore.IsKeyEntry(n));

            // Read Key from Aliases  
            if (keyAlias == null)
                throw new NotImplementedException("Alias");
            key = inputKeyStore.GetKey(keyAlias).Key;
            //Read certificate into 509 format
            return (X509Certificate)inputKeyStore.GetCertificate(keyAlias).Certificate;
        }
    }
```