# Certificate SHA1withRSA encryption method .NET Framework and .NET Core calculation results are inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
    public static string SignatureMessage(string certFileName, string password, byte[] dataTobeSign)
    {
        byte[] pfxCert = File.ReadAllBytes(certFileName);
        SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
        char[] pwdCharArray = password.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < pwdCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            pwd.AppendChar(pwdCharArray[i]);
        }

        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxCert, pwd);

        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
        signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26", "sha1");
        signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;

        ContentInfo signedData = new ContentInfo(dataTobeSign);
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(signedData, true);
        cms.ComputeSignature(signer);
        byte[] signature = cms.Encode();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
```

I'm trying this in .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework v4.6.1.

Can anyone help me?

The above code runs in the above environment list. The result is not the same. I can't upgrade to .NET Core because of this.

Completed issue reproduction dome github link [enter link description here](https://github.com/1290690484/DotNetCoreSignError)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671217/why-computesignature-in-net-framework-and-net-core-do-different-result

Comment: @TheGeneral I have tried this method. But it's so far from what I expected. And I don't have a private key file. I only have a certificate file and a password

Comment: The certificate file should contain the private key. Your .NET Core 3.1 app is using cryptography from .NET 6 Preview.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do I have to upgrade .net core 3.1 to .NET 6 Preview. I upgraded the encryption package in nuget to the latest Preview.
Is there any way to upgrade cryptography separately?

Comment: I would not use a preview version unless you are testing/validating for .NET 6. Since you are using .NET Core 3.1 you can choose the version of cryptography. As an example: **dotnet add package System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs --version 5.0.1** https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs/

Comment: @JohnHanley I upgraded System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs 5.0.1 and it did not solve the problem, I also went to try the latest preview version. The signature is still inconsistent with Framework